# Easy way to write this?

Tags: php

Is there an easy way to have this, so i don´t need to write all the time $lang in every variable ?

```
$lang = array();

$lang['PAGE_TITLE'] = 'My website page title';
$lang['HEADER_TITLE'] = 'My website header title';
$lang['SITE_NAME'] = 'My Website';
$lang['SLOGAN'] = 'my slogan">';
$lang['HEADING'] = 'Heading';
$lang['ABOUT'] = 'ABOUT english';
```

Thanks

Comment: PHP Arrays Manual: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php is pretty good documentation.

Comment: i suggest you to avoid all uppercase. it's a bad pratice

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
$lang = array(
    'PAGE_TITLE' => 'My website page title',
    'HEADER_TITLE' => 'My ...',
    // etc.
);
```